# Error when I want to create a user on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, password, useradd

I'm trying to run FreeBSD (.iso) in a virtual VMWare machine. The  `useradd` command gives me an error:

```
# useradd pstnc
useradd: Command not found
```

Why is that? The command is correct and very simple, just put `useradd` and then the password and that's it.

I tried to find a solution here and open a lot of other sites, but in all places talk about of creation of one new user, and none about what to do if it gives you an error like in my case!

Comment: It sounds like you have not yet read the [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/users-modifying.html).  You may want to start there, since it explicitly answers your question, and then come back here if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: ahhh .. ok, sorry about that, but honestly i was trying to find it, and not come here and just posting new themes, thank you and sorry

Comment: @ Larsks your answer is very good and i' m sure that is save a lot of time for another people to find you direct solution link., i spent one hour to try to find it and with not results .. i think that is a good ideea to post your message like a answer.

Comment: No problem...there ya go.

Comment: adduser and useradd are basically the same, Debian-like distros use adduser, the rest use useradd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/) is an excellent source of information about FreeBSD.  The [Modifying Accounts](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/users-modifying.html) section has explicit instructions for adding and removing users.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to create a user with `pw useradd -n myuser -s /bin/csh -m`

- **-n** user's name
- **-s** default shell
- **-m** creates home directory in `/home/USER`

(Don't forget to set the user's password)

My reasons for answering a 4 year old question:

- The question was never answered directly
- The links in the accepted answer not longer work
- I found the `man pw` page to be discombobulated

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD you could use `pw user add user_name` to add a new user

Or the `adduser` script